# Magento 2 tree view in Stores->Configuration

Tags: magento2, admin, system.xml, category-tree, checkbox

I'm starting to try to program in Magento. I have a problem creating a category tree in the configuration of my module.

I want to be able to choose a category. More than one. Just like in the photo with permissions. Can it be done and how?

Now I have multi-select but it's not very convenient.

Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do just like in the picture. But unfortunately it saves only one value for me :(
[image]

```
 <field id="ep_category" translate="label" type="checkboxes" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Wybierz katetegorie</label>
                <source_model>Test\Ep\Model\Config\Source\Category</source_model>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
            </field>
```